# ошибка при установке pip eel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, eel

понадобился плагин eel, во время установки была ошибка с visual studio, все установил, теперь новая ошибка. Вот ее текст:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                                     
     command: 'c:\users\владимир\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:
users\владимир\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep
17\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\18EE~1\AppData\Local\Temp
tmpcrgize8y'                                                                           
         cwd: C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gegor226\gevent_3ecc2ee7
be04dadaed632c5622bd7a4                                                                
    Complete output (77 lines):                                                        
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:                           
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: in
alid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)                                      
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.                                       
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:                           
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: in
alid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)                                      
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.                                       
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:                           
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: in
alid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)                                      
    running dist_info                                                                  
    creating C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-3ql5shei\gevent.e
g-info                                                                                 
    writing C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-3ql5shei\gevent.eg
-info\PKG-INFO                                                                         
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadat
-3ql5shei\gevent.egg-info\dependency_links.txt                                         
    writing entry points to C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-3q
5shei\gevent.egg-info\entry_points.txt                                                 
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-3q
5shei\gevent.egg-info\requires.txt                                                     
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata
3ql5shei\gevent.egg-info\top_level.txt                                                 
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-3ql
shei\gevent.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'                                                      
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-3ql
shei\gevent.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'                                                      
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'                                            
    warning: no files found matching 'changelog.rst'                                   
    warning: no files found matching 'Makefile.ext'                                    
    warning: no files found matching 'known_failures.py'                               
    warning: no files found matching '.pep8'                                           
    no previously-included directories found matching '*\__pycache__'                  
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distributio
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.o' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lo' found anywhere in distributio
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.la' found anywhere in distributio
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.dirstamp' found anywhere in distri
ution                                                                                  
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'config.log' found anywhere in distr
bution                                                                                 
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'config.status' found anywhere in di
tribution                                                                              
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'config.cache' found anywhere in dis
ribution                                                                               
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'                    
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distributi
n                                                                                      
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found under directory 's
c\greentest'                                                                           
    no previously-included directories found matching 'src\greentest\htmlcov'          
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'stamp-h?' found under directory 'de
s\c-ares'                                                                              
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'ares_build.h.orig' found under dire
tory 'deps\c-ares'                                                                     
    warning: no previously-included files matching '_corecffi.c' found under directory 
src\gevent'                                                                            
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'configure-output'            
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'configure-output.txt'        
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'deps\TAGS'                   
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'deps\c-ares\ares_build.h'    
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'deps\c-ares\ares_config.h'   
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'deps\c-ares\libcares.pc'     
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'deps\c-ares\libtool'         
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'deps\c-ares\Makefile'        
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\c-ares\.deps'              
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\c-ares\.libs'              
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libev\.deps'               
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libev\.libs'               
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'Makefile' found under directory 'de
s\libev'                                                                               
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'libtool' found under directory 'dep
\libev'                                                                                
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'stamp-h?' found under directory 'de
s\libev'                                                                               
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'config.h' found under directory 'de
s\libev'                                                                               
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libuv\.deps'               
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libuv\.libs'               
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libuv\src\.deps'           
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libuv\src\unix\.deps'      
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libuv\src\win\.deps'       
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libuv\test\.deps'          
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libuv\autom4te.cache'      
    no previously-included directories found matching 'deps\libuv\m4'                  
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'Makefile' found under directory 'de
s\libuv'                                                                               
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'Makefile.in' found under directory 
deps\libuv'                                                                            
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'ar-lib' found under directory 'deps
libuv'                                                                                 
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'aclocal.m4' found under directory '
eps\libuv'                                                                             
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'compile' found under directory 'dep
\libuv'                                                                                
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'configure' found under directory 'd
ps\libuv'                                                                              
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'depcomp' found under directory 'dep
\libuv'                                                                                
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'install-sh' found under directory '
eps\libuv'                                                                             
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'libtool' found under directory 'dep
\libuv'                                                                                
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'libuv.pc' found under directory 'de
s\libuv'                                                                               
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'ltmain.sh' found under directory 'd
ps\libuv'                                                                              
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'missing' found under directory 'dep
\libuv'                                                                                
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-3ql
shei\gevent.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'                                                      
    creating 'C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-3ql5shei\gevent.
ist-info'                                                                              
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'                                               
    ----------------------------------------                                           
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\владимир\appdata\local\program
\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\владимир\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\
ib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C
\Users\18EE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcrgize8y' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Помогите, 2 час уже долбаюсь.

Comment: Вижу что проблема с кодировкой -_- Пишет что не может через UTF-8 расшифровать какой-то байт и из-за этого возникает ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно установить `wheel` -

```
pip install wheel
```

И далее -

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Референс -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862371/14230861